# When storing the current date, should it be set in the web application or in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Say you're building a web application like a message board, in which you want to record the time when a message is submitted. There's no need to further process the date in any way. Is there any practical difference between getting the date in the application itself or generating it in the database? Is one method recommended over the other? If so, why?

```
$msg = "Stuff";

//Generating the date in the application
$currentTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$st = $mysqli->prepare("insert into messages (msg, date_time) values (?, ?)");
$st->bind_param("ss", $msg, $currentTime);

//--- OR ---

//Generating the date in the database
$st = $mysqli->prepare("insert into messages (msg, date_time) values (?, CURRENT_TIME())");
$st->bind_param("s", $msg);
```

Also, would the second option be better implemented by using a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the `date_time` field or it doesn't make much difference?

Answer (score 1):

If the database and the web server are located on a single server, it won't matter. Their times would be the same.

You can either:

- save the datetime under UTC+0
- save the timestamp by using PHP's `time()`

and let the application perform time zone adjustment and/or timestamp to datetime conversion.